# Can we get index from series data in highcharts

Tags: highcharts

Having a highchart, in which there are multiple lines, how can i get index of array data from which the point has been derived.

```
 this.series.data.indexOf( this.point)
```

It gives correct index of the point from line. But i need the index of the array from which series data has been loaded.

Comment: So you nee to have a index of point in particular serie or find point in all series ?

Comment: Need to find point from all series

Comment: So use a loop over each serie and refer to data. Then check if indexOf point in current serie,

Answer (score 1):

To get the index of a particular series you just use

```
this.series.index
```

with 0 being the first series.

Answer (score 1):

**There is a bug in yourChart.series.index selector:**

It works normal when you add new series with `yourChart.addSeries({..})` and it updates indexes.
But after you delete some series with `yourChart.series[series.index].remove()` it not updates indexes, until you add one more series.

Though, if you need to delete couple series one by one, you should select particular series by using simply `yourChart.series` array:

```
for (i in yourChart.series) {
  // your search condition, for example by name
  if (searchByName === chart.series[i].name) {
    chart.series[i].remove();
  }
}
```

where `i` is real index, not `series.index`!

Although, you can't select corect index by property `chart.series.index` which you can access at `yourChart.series.options.index`, you can't select series using it.